# Install locally a plugin downloaded via svn

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I need to install a grails plugin for my aplication provided from a SVN repository, but I have no Idea on how to do this. I had already done the checkout to the repository, but netbeans opens it as a new grails project.
I was reading that it can be specify it using the maven-install command in the terminal, but I don't know how to use it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks :)

Comment: easiest way would be as an inline plugin https://bowerstudios.com/node/1166 (you would add the line to the bottom of the BuildConfig.groovy) alternatively http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#12.1%20Creating%20and%20Installing%20Plug-ins

Comment: What @vahid said.  Especially using `grails.plugin.location.theplugin` if you plan to develop further on the plugin or by just installing it locally with `grails maven-install`

Comment: sorry I got loads of examples for more complex ones where the folder does not match the actual plugin name refer here: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testjenkins/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L79 //grails.plugin.location.'jenjir' = "../grails-jenkins-plugin"